# How to reconstruct diff data with leading NAs using diffinv in R?

Tags: r, matrix, diff, cumsum

I have a large data matrix (“trial.matrix”) similar to the one below.

```
         [,1] [,2]
[1,]    3   NA
[2,]    5   NA
[3,]    7   NA
[4,]    9   10
[5,]   11   12
[6,]   13   14
```

My problem requires that I shuffle some rows of the difference version of this matrix and then reconstruct a matrix from the shuffled difference matrix. When I apply diff(trial.matrix) I get:

```
    [,1] [,2]
[1,]    2   NA
[2,]    2   NA
[3,]    2   NA
[4,]    2    2
[5,]    2    2
```

To reconstruct the original data frame, I need to use cumsum() or diffinv(), e.g.:

```
new.df <- diffinv(diff(trial.matrix), xi = t(c(3, 10)))
```

but this gives:

```
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    3   10
[2,]    5   NA
[3,]    7   NA
[4,]    9   NA
[5,]   11   NA
[6,]   13   NA
```

Obviously, the beginning value (“xi”) for column 2 has to be applied starting in row 3 (or 4?). I have a number of columns in the real matrix, some with leading NAs and some without. I need to preserve the leading NAs in the reconstruction. I cannot figure out an easy way to reconstruct the columns with NAs in the difference matrix in a straightforward way.

(For each column I am able to construct two vectors, one containing the first non-NA row, and the other containing the first NA value, but cannot figure out a straightforward way to use these.)

Suggestions appreciated.

Comment: I don't think it is possible in general case. Imagine that your second column after shuffling is `c(NA,2,NA,2,NA)`--how many values outside of this vector would you need to reconstruct the column? Are you sure you can't obtain what you want by shuffling the trial matrix?

Comment: I should clarify. I will always have the lead NAs at the very top of the matrix. Other NAs down into the data can be handled with an na.X operation. It’s only the lead NAs I am concerned about. And, there are reasons why the NAs at the top need to stay there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can temporarily replace NAs by zeroes:

```
trial.matrix <- matrix(c(seq(3,13,by=2),rep(NA,3),10,12,14),ncol=2)

xi <- apply(trial.matrix,2,function(cl) cl[which(!is.na(cl))[1]])

z2 <- diff(trial.matrix)

# temporarily replace NAs in the second column by zeroes:
nas <- which(is.na(z2[,2]))
z2[nas,2] <- 0

new.df <- diffinv(z2,xi = t(xi))

# return NAs
new.df[nas,2] <- NA

#      [,1] [,2]
# [1,]    3   NA
# [2,]    5   NA
# [3,]    7   NA
# [4,]    9   10
# [5,]   11   12
# [6,]   13   14
```